# Rendering and updating google markers is too slow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I used to use Google maps V2 and had no problems with performance.  After I had to upgrade to V3 I noticed that rendering the markers had a considerable effect on the browser and often makes it hang just slightly.  As I am updating the markers every 10seconds or so this can have a profound effect.

Is there something I'm doing wrong as everywhere I've read suggests V3 is an improvement on speed.  Even map panning seems slower.

Debugging to console showed updating markers can take upto 120ms seconds i.e. setPosition().  However it's strange when I plot the markers for the first time it is almost instant and adding markers only takes 10ms.

Here is the code:

```
function createMarkerWithHandler(device, point, marker_type, dPoint)
{
    bounds_.extend(point);

    var lblclass = "markerLabel";
    var marker_display_text = device.dpt;
    var zIndex = getMarkerZIndex(marker_type);
    var qp = 0;

    lblclass += device.ol==STATUS_NOLOCK ? " m_nl" : " m_ol");

    if(device.qp > 0)
        qp = device.qp;

    var tracker = trackingcache_.getTracker(device.id); 

    if(tracker.isValid()) {
        // update
        tracker.update({
            zIndex: zIndex,
            layer: qp,
            labelClass: lblclass,
            labelStyle: {zIndex: zIndex },
            position: point
        });     
    } else {
        // create the google maps marker
        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
               map: layout_.Map,
               icon: customIcons_[marker_type],            
               position: point,
               draggable: false,
               zIndex: zIndex,
               labelContent: marker_display_text,
               labelClass: lblclass, // the CSS class for the label
               labelStyle: { zIndex: zIndex },
               layer: qp
             });

        tracker = trackingcache_.add(device.id, marker);        
    }

    tracker.setEventListener({
        device: device,
        location: dPoint
    });

    lblclass = null;
    marker_display_text = null;
    zIndex = null;
    device = null;
    dPoint = null;

    // add it to our tracking cache
    return tracker;
}

function TrackerObj(deviceid, marker)
{
    this.marker_ = marker;
    this.valid_ = deviceid.length > 0;
    this.id_ = deviceid;
    this.updated_ = this.valid_;
    this.eventListener_ = null;
    this.options_ = null;

    this.unregisterEventListener = function() {
        if(this.eventListener_) {
            google.maps.event.removeListener(this.eventListener_);
            this.eventListener_ = null;
        }
    };

    this.registerEventListener = function() {       
        var me = this;

        if(this.options_) {
            this.addListener(function() {
                closure_getGeoAddress(me.options_.device, this, me.options_.location, me.getLatLng());
            });                 
        }
    };
};

TrackerObj.prototype.update = function(options) {
    var current;
    var labelClass;

    var marker = this.getMarker();
    if(marker) {
        labelClass = marker.get("labelClass");

        if(labelClass !== options.labelClass) {
            marker.label.setLayer(options.layer);
            marker.set("labelClass", options.labelClass);
            marker.setZIndex(options.zIndex);
        }

        current = this.getLatLng();

        if(!current.equals(options.position)) {         
            // NOTE:  This code is taking upto 100ms
            marker.setPosition(options.position);           
        }       
    }

    this.updated_ = true;
};
TrackerObj.prototype.setEventListener = function(options) {
    this.options_ = options;

    if(!this.eventListener_) {          
        this.registerEventListener();
    }           
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For animated markers, set `optimized: false` in the `MarkerOptions` object. This will disable the use of canvas markers and revert to DOM based markers like in V2. This is already the case for draggable markers.

Comment: I don't think my markers are animated, although I'll try your suggestion.  Is there something in my code that would indicate they are?